# About the partial derivative respect to a scalar

Tags: determinant, partial-derivative, matrix-calculus, chain-rule

I have an equation $L(\alpha)=\frac{1}{2}\log |\Phi(\alpha I)\Phi^{\rm T}+\beta I|$ where $\Phi$ is a matrix, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are scalars. And I want to get $\frac{\partial L(\alpha)}{\partial \alpha}$. Hence, I apply the chain rule and will have:

Firstly, set $X(\alpha)=\Phi(\alpha I)\Phi^{\rm T}+\beta I$, then will have
$$
\frac{\partial L(\alpha)}{\partial \alpha}=\frac{\partial L(\alpha)}{\partial |X(\alpha)|}\frac {\partial |X(\alpha)|}{\partial X(\alpha)}\frac{\partial X(\alpha)}{\partial \alpha}
$$
After that I use the result in Matrix Cookbook (Page 9) which is 
$$
\frac{\partial det(X)}{\partial X}=det(X)(X^{-1})^{\rm T}
$$
then will have:
$$
\frac{\partial L(\alpha)}{\partial \alpha}=\frac{1}{2}[(\Phi(\alpha I)\Phi^{\rm T}+\beta I)^{-1}]^{\rm T}\Phi\Phi^{\rm T}
$$
However, this is contradict to the foregoing result in Cookbook (Page 8) which is

$$
\frac{\partial det(Y)}{\partial x}=det(Y)Tr[Y^{-1}\frac{\partial Y}{\partial x}]
$$

My classmate told me to use the second rule, however, I still don't know why I should use it and why I cannot use the foregoing chain rule to prove it?

Could anybody help me out about that?

Comment: Lest you lose faith in the Cookbook, your problem is with the last 2 terms on the right. You must use the double-contraction product, not the single-contraction product. Where the double-dot product is the product form of the trace function, i.e. $$A:B={\rm tr}(A^TB)$$Single-contractions are used for vectors, but double-contractions are used for matrix variables.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and I learn a lot from your answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For ease of typing, let 
$$\eqalign{
 X &= \alpha \Phi\Phi^T + \beta I  \,\,\implies dX = \Phi\Phi^T\,d\alpha \cr
 \lambda &= 2L \cr
}$$
Then we calculate the function, differential, and gradient as
$$\eqalign{
 \lambda &= \log(\det(X)) \cr\cr
d\lambda &= d\log(\det(X)) \cr
 &= X^{-T}:dX \cr
 &= X^{-T}:\Phi\Phi^T\,d\alpha \cr\cr
\frac{\partial\lambda}{\partial\alpha}
 &= X^{-T}:\Phi\Phi^T \cr
 &= {\rm tr}(X^{-1}\Phi\Phi^T) \cr
}$$
Or, in terms of the original variables
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial L}{\partial\alpha}
  &= \frac{1}{2}{\rm tr}\Big((\alpha \Phi\Phi^T + \beta I)^{-1}\Phi\Phi^T\Big) \cr
}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer! But I am still not so clear about why we should use double contractions when doing derivative respect to variable. Could you explain it or could you provide me some relevant books where I can get those basic knowledge? Sorry about that, but as a freshman learning matrix calculus, I really get lose when facing the complex derivative.